# string replace method to be replaced by regular expression

Tags: regex, pandas

I am using string replace method to clean-up column names.

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.replace("#$%./- ","").str.replace(' ', '_').str.replace('.', '_').str.replace('(','').str.replace(')','').str.replace('.','').str.lower()
```

Though it works, certainly does not look pythonic. Any suggestion?
I need only A-Za-z and underscore _ if required as column names.

---

Update:

I tried using Regular expression in the first replace method, but I still need to chain the string like this...

```
terms.columns=terms.columns.str.replace(r"^[^a-zA-Z1-9]*", '').str.replace(' ', '_').str.replace('(','').str.replace(')','').str.replace('.', '').str.replace(',', '')
```

---

Update showing test data:

Original string (Tab separated):

```
[Sr.No. Course  Terms   Besic of Education  Degree Course   Course Approving Authority (i.e Medical Council, etc.)  Full form of Course 1 year Duration 2nd year    3rd year Duration   4 th year Duration]
```

Change column names:

```
terms.columns=terms.columns.str.replace(r"^[^a-zA-Z1-9]*", '').str.replace(' ', '_').str.replace('(','').str.replace(')','').str.replace('.', '').str.replace(',', '').str.lower()
```

Output:

```
['srno', 'course', 'terms', 'besic_of_education', 'degree_course',
       'course_approving_authority_ie_medical_council_etc',
       'full_form_of_course', '1_year_duration', '2nd_year_',
       '3rd_year_duration', '4_th_year_duration']
```

Above output is correct. The question: Is there any way to achive the same other than the way I have used?

Comment: Please show some test data and expected output.

Comment: Try `df.columns.str.replace("[^\w\s]+","").str.replace("\s+","_").str.lower()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a smaller number of `.replace` operations by replacing non-word strings with an empty string and subsequently removing the whitespace characters with an underscore.

```
df.columns.str.replace("[^\w\s]+","").str.replace("\s+","_")‌​.str.lower()
```

I hope this helps.